# ubuntu fails to start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have a laptop with ubuntu 9.10 which fails to start, and I want to copy the data from it to an external hard disk. I can login in recovery mode command line, but then I cannot mount the external hard drive. (in recovery mode I cannot write to the laptops hard drive)

If I boot from an portable USB with mintlinux, I can mount the external harddrive, and copy most of the data from the laptop, however there is a dir which I have no rights to access under /home/user/Documents
then I get a permission denied error. Are there any other options?

Comment: `chown` the stuff you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you boot with mintlinux I propose in this case, you should do all the copying as root. Then there shouldn't be any permission problems.

Comment: indeed that is what should be the case, and all files under /home/username can be copied. however, there is this perticular dir /home/username/Documents which is not accessible, nor can i take over the permissions. i can only view the 2 subfolders, but it cannot enter those directories. only from ubuntu recovery command line i can enter those dirs... any suggestion of what could be blocking access?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are root, you may need to `chown root:root` the files before you can access them.